# How to join fields of an array of objects in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array like this

```
const array = [{a: '1', b: '2'}, {a: '3', b: '4' }];
```

I want to join the only field into a string to have a result like this: '1, 3'

The join function of an array can only be used on the whole entry, not on fields of the object that is underneath. Is there a way to do this with standard functionality or do I have to use a for loop or a forEach?

Comment: you'll need a loop, I'd go for a .map

Answer (score 7):

Before `join` you need [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) array

```js
const array = [
    { a: '1', b: '2' },
    { a: '3', b: '4' },
];

const result = array.map(_ => _.a).join(', ');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform this through For loop.

```
result = [];
const array = [{ a: '1', b: '2' }, { a: '3', b: '4' }];
array.forEach(elm => result.push(elm.a));
console.log(result.join(", "));
// 1, 3
```